# I am trying add verify jwt token method in google cloud function but its showing error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying create Node.js function in GCP (without express just normal http function as shown below)

```
const jwksRsa = require(‘jwks-rsa’);
const jwt = require(‘express-jwt’);

const checkJwt = jwt({
provided by the JWKS endpoint.
secret: jwksRsa.expressJwtSecret({
cache: true,
rateLimit: true,
jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
jwksUri: added
}),

// Validate the audience and the issuer.
audience: ‘addedi’,
issuer: added,
algorithms: added
});

exports.sampleFunctionAuth = (req, res, checkJwt) => {
res.send(“Hello”);
};
```

how to call checkJwt function ?
any code snippet if possible ?

It’s not working in gcp function . Can any one help me with this .

Thanks and Regards,
Tapas

Comment: Howdy .... welcome to Stackoverflow.  Looking at your code fragment, it isn't clear what you are asking.  Can you elaborate on your question?  What is your high level thinking and intent.

Comment: 1) Format your code correctly in your question. 2) What are the `added` values? 3) What is the exact error? 4) How are you calling this endpoint? - show a `curl` example. 5) Develop on your desktop then port to Cloud Functions.

Comment: Make your code working with express webserver, and then you could deploy on Cloud Function easily. Your code is too light, check some tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it is not clear what the error you are encountering is.

However, I did notice that you have many syntax-related error in your code. For instance, when specifying your module names: `const jwksRsa = require(‘jwks-rsa’);` you are not using the right character to specify that `jwks-rsa` is a string. In other words, you are using a [`left single quotation mark`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%80%98) as opposed to a [`single quotation mark`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%27) or a [`grave accent (aka back-tick)`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%60). I see this issue repeated throughout your code so I would fix those beforehand.

Moreover, in `res.send(“Hello”);`, you are not using a [`double quotation mark`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%22) but are in fact using a [`left double quotation mark`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%E2%80%9C) which again could pose issues since you javascript expects either a `single quotation mark ( ' )`, `double quotation mark ( " )` or a `back-tick` ( ` ) to specify strings.

Clear up these issues first, then edit your post with the aforementioned changes and further details with regards to the error encountered, should it persist.